# I need to swap the ip and port of intranet sites

Tags: 2013, network

We have an old intranet site that needed updated. I built a new intranet site on SharePoint 2013. Now that the site is ready so I want to swap the IP address and port of the two sites. How do I accomplish this? I tried updating the bindings in IIS but I get an  "HTTP 404 Not Found" error.

Comment: are you using the IP address in the AAM? or You need to update the DNS record?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The network admin updated the DNS record and it started working. Thanks!

Comment: Let me add that as an answer so that community get Benefit from it.

Comment: just did, please mark it answer...and upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, You have to do couple of things.

- update the DNS record.
- Update the IIS bindings with proper port
- Update the AAM settings at Central admin.